# Ionic 4: 'Typescript error' in helperService Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at HelperService

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Getting error 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at HelperService.addCommasToArray' when trying to loop through an array that has been passed as a paramter in a helperService class [Typescript]

I'm really not sure why this is not working - I believe it should be straightforward - all I'm trying to do is pass in an array as a parameter and add a ',' to every value in the array (except the last value)

Here is my HelperService Class method:

```
 export class HelperService {

   constructor() { }

    /*
    * Add commas to every value in the array except for the last value
    */
     addCommasToArray(array: Array<any>) : Array<any> {

         for (let i = 0; array.length; i++){
              array[i] += ", ";
             }
         return array;
         }     
 }
```

I then call this method within the ngInit of another ts class

```
  this.helperService.addCommasToArray(this.previousClubs);
```

Here is the ngInit method

```
  public previousClubs: Array<any>;

     constructor(private playersService: PlayersService,private 
      helperService: HelperService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
     const playerId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.playersService.getPlayerDetails(playerId).get()
      .then(playerDetailsSnapshot=> {
          this.currentPlayerDetails = playerDetailsSnapshot.data();
          this.currentPlayerDetails.id = playerDetailsSnapshot.id;    
      });

     /*
      * Return Previous Clubs 
      */
        this.playersService.getPreviousClubs(playerId).get().then( 
 previousClubsSnapshot =>{
         this.previousClubs = [];
             previousClubsSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                 this.previousClubs.push({
                     id: snap.id,
                     name: snap.data().name,
                 });
                 return false;
             });        
         }); 

        this.helperService.addCommasToArray(this.previousClubs);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here:

```
this.playersService.getPreviousClubs(playerId).get().then( 
 previousClubsSnapshot =>{
         this.previousClubs = [];
             previousClubsSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                 this.previousClubs.push({
                     id: snap.id,
                     name: snap.data().name,
                 });
                 return false;
             });        
         });
// this line executes without awaiting for .then enclosed scope
this.helperService.addCommasToArray(this.previousClubs);
```

Basically you call addCommasToArray even before your previousClubs var gets array assigned to it and then gets all its items pushed in. To fix since your method is (.then) async you need to call for this method inside the .then execution scope:

```
ngOnInit() {
     const playerId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.playersService.getPlayerDetails(playerId).get()
      .then(playerDetailsSnapshot=> {
          this.currentPlayerDetails = playerDetailsSnapshot.data();
          this.currentPlayerDetails.id = playerDetailsSnapshot.id;    
      });

     /*
      * Return Previous Clubs 
      */
        this.playersService.getPreviousClubs(playerId).get().then( 
 previousClubsSnapshot =>{
         this.previousClubs = [];
         previousClubsSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                 this.previousClubs.push({
                     id: snap.id,
                     name: snap.data().name,
                 });
                 return false;
             });        
         });
         this.helperService.addCommasToArray(this.previousClubs);
     }
```